# Rust Compile Error with use of possibly-uninitialized when the logic is sound

Tags: rust

So I have a rust code that acts as a CLI, it has a `-o filename.txt` kind of optional syntax which if given makes the program write some contents to a file, if not given it skips the file writing part.

A simple code without any of the complicated variable comes down to this:

```rust
    fn main() {
        let x:i64; // define the file
        let y = true; // if -o is present, false otherwise (it'll be mut)
        if y {
            x = 1; // open file in argument of -o
        }

        // some other logics and actions, it won't change y.

        if y {
            println!("{}", x); // write to file
        }
    }
```

So basically the value of x will be initialized and accessed only when `y` is true, so it'll never be accessed uninitialized. But rust throws this error:

```
error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `x`
  --> src/main.rs:11:21
   |
11 |         println!("{}", x); // write to file
   |                        ^ use of possibly-uninitialized `x`
```

So there is similar problem solved in this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647311/borrow-of-possibly-uninitialized-variable-error-in-obviously-unreachable-blo)

But unlike that question i need y be a variable so the if statement needs to be checked in runtime instead of compile time. Is there a way to compile it by telling the compiler it's ok?

Actual code is here (to avoid asking the wrong question as the solution could be to use a different method instead of forcing the compiler):

```
[dependencies]
clap={ version = "3.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

```rust
use std::{io, thread, time};
use std::io::Write;     // for flush
use std::fs;
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser)]
struct Cli {
    /// Do not clear output file before writing to it
    #[clap(short, long, action)]
    append: bool,
    /// Output File to write the captured contents.
    #[clap(parse(from_os_str), short, long, default_value = "")]
    output: std::path::PathBuf,
}


fn main() {
    let args = Cli::parse();

    let mut out_to_file = false;
    if !args.output.as_os_str().is_empty() {
      out_to_file = true;
    }
    
    let mut file;
    if out_to_file {
      file = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .append(args.append)
        .truncate(!args.append)
        .open(args.output)
        .unwrap();
    }

    let clip_new = "Test String";
    let separator = "\n";
    loop {
      print!("{}{}", clip_new, separator);
      io::stdout().flush().unwrap();

      if out_to_file{
        file.write_all(clip_new.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write to file.");
        file.write_all(separator.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write to file.");
      }

      thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
}
```

So the current workaround I have is to have file always initialized.

My current workaround opens a temp file, and uses it to write the output if user does want a output file. But I'd prefer to not open a file if user doesn't want it.

```rust
    let mut out_file = env::temp_dir().join("testfile.txt");
    if !args.output.as_os_str().is_empty() {
        out_file = args.output;
    }
```

Using this and opening `out_file` instead of `args.output` without any conditional checks (removing all `if out_to_file`).

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution while still drafting this question so I'll leave it here.

The solution was to use `Option<fs::File>` which can be `None`.
So, `let mut file:Option<fs::File> = None;` will keep `file` initialized, but without having to open a dummy file. And real file can be put with `Some`.

```rust
use std::{io, thread, time};
use std::io::Write;     // for flush
use std::fs;
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser)]
struct Cli {
    /// Do not clear output file before writing to it
    #[clap(short, long, action)]
    append: bool,
    /// Output File to write the captured contents.
    #[clap(parse(from_os_str), short, long, default_value = "")]
    output: std::path::PathBuf,
}


fn main() {
    let args = Cli::parse();

    let out_to_file = if !args.output.as_os_str().is_empty() {
        true
    } else {
        false
    };
    
    let mut file:Option<fs::File> = None;
    if out_to_file {
    file = Some(fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .append(args.append)
        .truncate(!args.append)
        .open(args.output)
        .unwrap());
    }

    let clip_new = "Test String";
    let separator = "\n";
    loop {
    print!("{}{}", clip_new, separator);
    io::stdout().flush().unwrap();

    if out_to_file{
        file.as_ref().unwrap().write_all(clip_new.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write to file.");
        file.as_ref().unwrap().write_all(separator.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write to file.");
    }

    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
    }
}
```

Equivalent solution to the dummy problem

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x:Option<i64> = None; // definite the file as Option
    let y = true; // if -o is present, false otherwise (it'll not be mut)
    if y {
        x = Some(1); // open file in argument of -o as Some
    }

    // some other logics and actions, it won't change y.

    if y {
        println!("{}", x.unwrap()); // write to file after .unwrap()
    }
}
```

Comment: `Option` would be my recommended approach. One minor improvement could be to use `if let Some(x) = x { ... }` or `if let Some(x) = &x { ... }` instead of another `if y { ... }` if the intention is "if `x` is initialized, then do `...`", since that lets you avoid an `.unwrap()` call (which shouldn't panic but could panic if you refactored for example one if condition without also updating the other). See [modified playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cb77410d565c70cf1c0d5b3f1a87d26e).

Comment: Thanks, but what does `if let Some(x) = x` do? And looks like using `let Some(file) = file` in the file example in last conditional doesn't compile. I tried `!file.is_none()` and it works, so it'll be better then storing another bool.

Comment: @Atreyagaurav [Conditional if let Expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#conditional-if-let-expressions) and [Concise Control Flow with if let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-03-if-let.html)